# The pool genesis transactions are not compatible with protocol version

Tags: c#, .net, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-indy

I'm having a challenge running a '*Write a DID and Query its Verkey*' sample code from hyperledger it keeps giving me an error

> The pool genesis transactions are not compatible with protocol version

How can I handle this ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when trying to connect to my local indy pool. For me, i forgot to add this line where the protocol version is set.

```
await Pool.SetProtocolVersionAsync(2);
```